# Como criar um dicionario e auto incrementar os valores?

Tags: python, dicionário

Preciso criar um dicionário a partir de uma lista de inteiros, onde cada chave contém o valor da somas que está na lista:

```
t = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[1,1],[2,2],[1,2]]
dicionario = {}
for i in t:
    dicionario[str(i[0])] = 0
for i in t:
    dicionario[str(i[0])] += i[1]
```

Onde meu dicionario teria o resultado: `{'1':5,'2':3,'3':1,'4':1}`

Porém estou fazendo dois loops como podem ver, mas como preciso que esta tarefa seja a mais rápida possível, ou seja, com apenas um loop como eu faria isso?

```
t = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[1,1],[2,2],[1,2]]
dicionario = {}
for i in t:
    dicionario[str(i[0])] += i[1]
```

---

```
KeyError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8eda406a14d0> in <module>()
      1 for i in t:
----> 2     dicionario[str(i[0])] += i[1]
      3 

KeyError: '1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer usando [`setdefault`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/dictionary_setdefault.htm), e sim, é escusado usar dois ciclos:

```
t = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[1,1],[2,2],[1,2]]
dicionario = {}
for k, v in t: # unpacking dos valores de cada sublista
    dicionario[k] = dicionario.setdefault(k, 0) + v
print(dicionario) # {1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

`setdefault`, caso não exista já a chave no dict, vai atribuir um valor `default` (segundo argumento) à nova do key (primeiro argumento) inserida no dict.

De uma maneira um pouco mais perceptível/legível:

```
t = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[1,1],[2,2],[1,2]]
dicionario = {}
for k, v in t: # unpacking dos valores de cada sublista
    if k not in dicionario:
        dicionario[k] = 0
    dicionario[k] += v
print(dicionario) # {1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

Como apontado e bem em comentário, aqui com com o uso de [`get`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) terias o mesmo resultado final, apesar de ser um pouco mais lento a diferença é irrisória neste caso:

```
t = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[1,1],[2,2],[1,2]]
dicionario = {}
for k, v in t: # unpacking dos valores de cada sublista
    dicionario[k] = dicionario.get(k, 0) + v
print(dicionario) # {1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

[`get` vs `setdefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423428/python-dict-get-vs-setdefault)

Comment: Aproveitando, poderia também colocar a opção de `dicionario.get(k, default=0)`? Mesmo tendo algumas particularidades quando comparada ao `setdefault` acredito que valha a pena citar, até pela legibilidade do código.

Comment: Obgado  @AndersonCarlosWoss, adicionada essa alternativa