# Agrupar nome em mesmo grupo

Tags: python

Tenho uma tabela de vendas com nome dos vendedores, produtos e demais informações importada de uma planilha `xlsx`.

Porém acontece que o nomes dos vendedores aparecem repetidos conforme as vendas, por exemplo:

```
João  - Venda de produto A 
Marco - Venda de produto B
João - Venda de produto B
João - Venda de produto A
```

No exemplo acima, eu queria que somassem todas as vendas do "João" para comparar com as do "Marco" por exemplo, e não que o gráfico repetisse o nome dele *ad infinitum*.

Comment: Como tens os dados originalmente? Em que formato? Lista, csv, tal como puseste (string)?

Comment: O arquivo é uma tabela do excel em xlsx - ai tem a coluna "vendedores" que como disse a cada venda repete o nome do cara. Ai vem outras informações como valores, etc etc

Comment: Aqui, segue um print da tela [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gR4CWRMHGDXydUsOwDsPtvgT-6rvAcBU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Esqueci de complementar, viu ai, o "Andre" aparece 3 vezes. O "Paulo" 2...era para aparecer o total de cada um junto e não separado para fazer o comparativo de vendas.

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você tenha uma lista de tuplas do tipo:

```
[ ('JOAO', 10.50), ( 'JOAO', 33.10 ), ('MARCO', 4.00 ), ('JOAO', 15.99), ('MARCO', 21.54) ]
```

Que tal:

```
vendas = [ ('JOAO', 10.50), ( 'JOAO', 33.10 ), ('MARCO', 4.00 ), ('JOAO', 15.99), ('MARCO', 21.54) ]

totais = {}

for vendedor, venda in vendas:
    if vendedor in totais:
        totais[vendedor] += venda
    else:
        totais[vendedor] = venda

print(totais)
```

Saída:

```
{'MARCO': 25.54, 'JOAO': 59.59}
```

Você também pode usar um `defaultdict` para simplificar a solução:

```
from collections import defaultdict

vendas = [ ('JOAO', 10.50), ( 'JOAO', 33.10 ), ('MARCO', 4.00 ), ('JOAO', 15.99), ('MARCO', 21.54) ];

totais = defaultdict(float)

for vendedor, venda in vendas:
    totais[vendedor] += venda

print(dict(totais))
```

Saída:

```
{'MARCO': 25.54, 'JOAO': 59.59}
```

Comment: E como eu faria isso com um arquivo importado .xlsx ?

Comment: Estou apertando enter sem querer...bem, tem uma coluna onde só se encontra os nomes, e por exemplo até a linha 55 só tem "Paulo", em seguida "Andre" e assim por diante com outros vendedores.

Comment: Sem uma amostra do arquivo de entrada e uma boa explicação do que você quer dizer com "importado" fica dificil elaborar uma resposta mais adequada.

Comment: Segue print do arquivo de entrada [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fat0SVzb93GrHoZs4pHKKL_9K2ha9lPk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Nem precisas de importar `defaultdict` neste caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271026/como-criar-um-dicionario-e-auto-incrementar-os-valores/271029#271029

Answer (score 1):

Para ler o arquivo xlsx você pode usar a biblioteca openpyxl. Ela pode ser instalada usando o pip:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Baseado na resposta do Lacobus, o script ficaria assim:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='nome_do_arquivo.xlsx')

totais = {}

for row in wb['nome_da_planilha']:
    vendedor = row[0].value
    if vendedor in totais:
        totais[vendedor] += 1
    else:
        totais[vendedor] = 1

print(totais)
```